# Turbo and content_for - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, turbo

I'm trying to load a javascript only on a certain page. For that I'm using `<%= yield(:head) %>` in the `<head>` and the following on the page:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag "foo" %>
<% end %>
```

This works when clicking on a link to the page the first time. However when further I navigate anywhere and then go back again, Turbo conserves the head part (`<script type="module">import "foo"</script>`). Thus this script is not executed anymore.

Is there a way to tell turbo, that it shouldn't 'cache' this?

Answer (score 0):

ran into same problem. had to use `document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function() {} );` to load the js

## foo.js

```
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function() {
  console.log("foo.js loaded");
  // more js codes
});
```

Comment: I tried the same, but I didn't solve my problem, since the file stays after loading. This is not what I wanted. But thanks for your answer and sorry for my late response!!